# Spring security authentication using database

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am struggling with spring security authentication using database. Simply saying it doesn't work - i can't login on my user, it always redirects me to accessdenied.

application-security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/AddUser.html" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from user_authentication where username=?"
               authorities-by-username-query="select u1.username, u2.role from user_authentication u1, user_authorization u2 where u1.user_id = u2.user_id and u1.username =?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I have user = 'abcd' with password 'abcd'. Database query `select u1.username, u2.role from user_authentication u1, user_authorization u2 where u1.user_id = u2.user_id and u1.username ='abc'` returns 'abcd' with 'ROLE_ADMIN'. My login form must be ok (everything was ok when i was using hardcoded username and password in my application-security.xml). Also datasource is fine - it works for CRUD operations. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Any relevant things in logs ?

Answer (score 0):

In the form-login:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" 
    default-target-url="/AddUser.html" 
    authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
```

you dont't have any parameters like:

```
username-parameter="username"
password-parameter="password"
```

So just add them:

```
<form-login login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/AddUser.html" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
```